# child div expanding out of parent div issue

Tags: css, layout, html

I want something like [this, click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/326t3rhmyzm6n7q/layout.png).

This is a simple code in my HTML:

```css
  #mainContent {
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        height:600px;
        padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    }
    #mainContent #sidebar { /* sidebar inside #mainContent */
        float:left;
        width:220px;
        height:560px;
        margin:10px 10px 40px 10px;
        padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
    }
    #mainContent #featContent {
        height:560px;
        margin:10px 10px 40px 260px;
        padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="mainContent">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="featContent"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is one of the divs are improperly placed .The #featContent div is going out of its parent #mainContent div for reason I don't understand. Check out this in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dBdR/1/). The margin of #featContent goes out of the #mainContent bounds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dBdR/2/)***
Add the following style to the `#mainContent`

```
#mainContent {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dBdR/2/)***

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. :) But I don't understand. How not writing this screws up the layout? What overflow has to do with it?

Comment: OK, I read the desc in the link. It only says how it is used and not how it works? How does writing overflow makes this?

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to parent div

```
#mainContent {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 5px 40px 5px; background-color:red
}
#mainContent #sidebar { /* sidebar inside #mainContent */
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:560px;
    margin:10px 10px 40px 10px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
#mainContent #featContent {
    height:560px;  
    margin:10px 10px 40px 260px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    overflow:auto;
}​
```

Demo hrer http://jsfiddle.net/j4C7T/

Comment: if we are giving floats to our child container so we should clear the floats so if will give the overflow:hidden; into our parent div so child floated elements will be clear.... :-)

Comment: I need padding in the child divs because I don't want their content to stick to the edges of their background colour. Rohit Azad gave an answer which worked!

Comment: @Ajinx999 i m not talking about child elements padding im talking about #maincontent parent div padding so we should not give the padding there we can only use overflow:hidden; as rohit did we will get the solution.......